Child Not Persisting When Saving with Parent in JPA/Hibernate
I'm working with the following JPA entities:

Item has a @OneToMany relationship with both SubItem and Book.
When I persist an Item with multiple SubItems, everything works fine.
However, when I try to persist an Item with multiple Books, it saves
all the Books except the first one.
I've enabled SQL logging, and I can see all the INSERT statements
being executed, but when I check the database, the first Book is
missing from the Books table.

Here are my entities:
import jakarta.persistence.*;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

@Entity
public class Item {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "item")
    private Set<SubItem> subItems = new LinkedHashSet<>();

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "item")
    private Set<Book> books = new LinkedHashSet<>();
}

import jakarta.persistence.*;
import java.time.LocalDateTime;

@Entity
public class SubItem {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    private LocalDateTime createdAt;
    private String name;

    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "item_id")
    private Item item;
}


import jakarta.persistence.*;
import java.util.Objects;

@Entity
public class Book {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    private String title;

    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "item_id")
    private Item item;

}

So when doing the following
itemRepository.save() 

it only saved item, subitems, all books except the first Book in the set
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;
@Repository
public interface ItemRepository extends JpaRepository<Item, Long> {
    // Additional query methods (if needed) can be defined here
}




    public Item updateItem(Item inputItem) {
    // Fetch the existing Item from the database using the ID from the passed inputItem object
    Item existingItem = itemRepository.findById(inputItem.getId())
        .orElseThrow(() -> new RuntimeException("Item not found")); // Throw an exception if the Item is not found

    // Create a set for updated SubItems
    Set<SubItem> updatedSubItems = inputItem.getSubItems().stream().map(subItem -> {
        SubItem newSubItem = new SubItem(); // Create a new SubItem instance

        // Set the properties of the new SubItem from the incoming SubItem
        newSubItem.setName(subItem.getName()); // Set the SubItem's name
        newSubItem.setCreatedAt(subItem.getCreatedAt()); // Set the SubItem's creation date

        // If the SubItem has an ID, use it; otherwise, it will be generated as a new entity
        if (subItem.getId() != null) {
            newSubItem.setId(subItem.getId()); // Set the ID from the incoming SubItem
        }

        // Return the newly created or updated SubItem
        return newSubItem;
    }).collect(Collectors.toSet()); // Collect the mapped SubItems into a Set

    // Set the updated SubItems in the existingItem's SubItems collection
    existingItem.setSubItems(updatedSubItems);

    // Save and return the updated Item, including its updated SubItems, to the database
    return itemRepository.save(existingItem);
}

this is the test that fails because of only one Book inserted
import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertEquals;
import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertNotNull;

import org.junit.jupiter.api.BeforeEach;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.DataJpaTest;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

@DataJpaTest
@Transactional
public class ItemServiceTest {

    @Autowired
    private ItemRepository itemRepository;

    @BeforeEach
    void setUp() {
        // Clear all entities from the Item repository to ensure a clean state for each test
        itemRepository.deleteAll();
    }

    @Test
    public void testCreateItemWithSubItemsAndBooks() {
        // Create two SubItems
        SubItem subItem1 = new SubItem();
        subItem1.setName("SubItem 1");
        subItem1.setCreatedAt(LocalDateTime.now());

        SubItem subItem2 = new SubItem();
        subItem2.setName("SubItem 2");
        subItem2.setCreatedAt(LocalDateTime.now());

        Set<SubItem> subItems = new HashSet<>();
        subItems.add(subItem1);
        subItems.add(subItem2);

        // Create two Books
        Book book1 = new Book();
        book1.setTitle("Book 1");

        Book book2 = new Book();
        book2.setTitle("Book 2");

        Set<Book> books = new HashSet<>();
        books.add(book1);
        books.add(book2);

        // Create an Item with SubItems and Books
        Item inputItem = new Item();
        inputItem.setName("Item 1");
        inputItem.setSubItems(subItems);
        inputItem.setBooks(books);

        // Save the Item using itemRepository
        Item savedItem = itemRepository.save(inputItem);

        // Fetch the saved Item to verify the associations
        Item fetchedItem = itemRepository.findById(savedItem.getId())
            .orElseThrow(() -> new RuntimeException("Item not found"));

        // Verify SubItems
        assertNotNull(fetchedItem.getSubItems());
        assertEquals(2, fetchedItem.getSubItems().size());

        // Verify Books
        assertNotNull(fetchedItem.getBooks());
        assertEquals(2, fetchedItem.getBooks().size());
    }
}


Can you add the code where you do the persisting too ?

Just to make sure I'm understanding, you're saying JPA is persisting only some of the items in the books set?

yes, if I put 3 books it persists the 2nd and the 3rd but not the 1st. It only happens with Books. (I added the service code).

@alegria I added the service

You are replacing the collection of books in that existingItem.setBooks(updatedBooks); line... that's a red flag. Hibernate will instrument collections in managed entities so that they can be "watched" for changes like additions and deletions and so it can then generate the proper SQL statements it needs. You are effectively swapping out the existing managed collection for an unmanaged one. I would rather clear() and then addAll() to the existing one and see if that works better.

@Gimby tried that but didn't work too

What aren't you showing in these entities? You are using Sets for the collections which don't allow duplicates - if you've implemented an equals/hashcode implementation badly, you might be causing elements to go 'missing' from the set. Use a List instead to verify, and also be careful in general with equals/hashcode method implementations.

@Chris I tested with List but didn't work. I found out it's caused by cascade type remove which is included in Cascade ALL specified on the child. How could that be cause? I can't understand

Not to be argumentative, but that isn't likely the 'cause'. Try unit tests to reproduce your issue, and show the actual model you are 'persisting'. We cannot tell what is in that ItemDTO, but your code assumes it isn't new - it must exist so is a merge operation. Your code also handles books completely different, with a comment stating you are NOT passing in IDs so assume all books are new! If the Item already has a set of books, what do you expect to happen with those existing books? Hint: nothing will happen and they are left behind in the DB as is, still ref the item. A duplicate title

If you've tried using List and tried updating the code to use the existingItem's collection in place (instead of replacing it) show the latest code. Your code here likely has more than one issue that contributes to your problem - you should fix them all and see how they work together instead of one off and revert.

@Chris I updated the code with the correction of collections use and with adding a unit test that fails because of books

What do your asserts say if you run them on the inputItem prior to save and the savedItem right after the save call? What does a query for all books return? Where in your test are you setting the back pointers in books and subitems to the Item you are creating? And why is it still showing "Set" being used instead of List?

The way you "update" an existing subItem is also a red flag. You should not be creating a new instance and then setting an existing ID... you should be modifying the properties of the existing managed entity so Hibernate can do it's job. If you want to use Hibernate/JPA... do things the documented way.
